# Swift-y boolean expression - case outside if/switch

Tags: swift, option-type, boolean-expression

To continue to the next screen, a `patron` must have one of two identifiers. The code I've got to do this is:

```
let identifier1Entered = !patron.identifier1.isEmpty
let identifier2Entered = patron.identifier2 != nil && !patron.identifier2!.isEmpty
guard identifier1Entered || identifier2Entered else { return }
```

But it's not Swifty, I'm force-unwrapping the optional `identifier2`, because I don't want to expand this to a longer, and IMO messier

```
var identifier2Entered = false
if let identifier2 = patron.identifier2 where !identifier2.isEmpty {
  identifier2Entered = true
}
```

What I thought might work is just taking the expression out of the `if` statement, like:

```
let id2Entered = let identifier2 = patron.identifier2 where !identifier2.isEmpty
```

or

```
let id2Entered = case .Some(let id2) = patron.identifier2 where !id2.isEmpty
```

But it appears that these expressions are only allowed within `if` statements.
The other more Swifty solution I thought of is this:

```
let identifier1Entered = !patron.identifier1.isEmpty
guard let id2 = patron.identifier2 where !id2.isEmpty || identifier1Entered
  else { return }
```

But it requires that identifier2 is not nil, which is incorrect, and as far as I know, there's no way to use optional binding with `||` in `if` or `guard` statements. Not to mention that I feel it's less clear and readable than the force-unwrapping.

Anyone have a clear, more Swifty solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions using optional chaining:

```
let identifier2Entered = patron.identifier2?.isEmpty == false
let identifier2Entered = !(patron.identifier2?.isEmpty ?? true)
```

If `patron.identifier2` is `nil` then `patron.identifier2?.isEmpty`
evaluates to `nil`, and you'll get `false` as a result.

Comment: doh! Love the first answer